# GWT overlay types, converting to JSON

Tags: json, gwt

In GWT, what is the best way to convert a JavaScriptObject overlay type into a JSON string?

I currently have

```
public final String toJSON() {      
    return new JSONObject(this).toString();
}
```

Which seems to work fine. I would like to know if there are any better approaches.

Comment: Aside from using another library to do this, this is the best way.  It does require that you add <inherits name="com.google.gwt.json.JSON" /> to your GWT module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never actually tried that (only consumed JSON so far, never needed to produce it). This seems to be native browser/javascript functionality.

You *could* write it as:

```
public native String toJSON() /*-{
  return this.toString();
}-*/;
```

They essentially just do the exact same thing and likely result in identical JavaScript output. The optimizing compiler is really amazing.

Comment: Does this work? I implemented this exactly in an overlay type and it returns [object Object]. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @Eugen - see Nick's comment. As he mentions, most modern browsers will support `JSON.stringify()`. If you need to support a browser which doesn't, use a polyfill such as [JSON 3](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/).

Answer (score 2):

we have a JSNI method like that, but use douglas crockfords JSON library (in case the browser doesn't supply one natively):

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

```
public native String stringify() /*-{
  return JSON.stringify();
}-*/;
```

whats nice is that stringify can take parameters to pretty-print the output with a specified indentation... among other things